# I want to print table of 17 from 3 to 17 but my code throws error not converting 'x' and '=' into int

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, e-commerce, ssms-2016

```
declare @table int
set @table = 17

declare @loop int
set @loop = 3

declare @x varchar
set @x = 'x'

while(@loop <= 17)
begin
    print @table + cast(@x as varchar) + @loop + cast(' = ' as char) + @table * @loop
end
```

In this code you see `@x` and '='  which is not converting into int.

I get this error instead:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 67
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'x' to data type int.

I tried to convert `@x` to int as well as I changed data type of variable but it didn't work so far.

So I tried to put values of x and = into variables and change datatype on earlier stage but same problem occurred every time

Answer (score 0):

```sql
declare @table int
set @table=17
declare @loop int
set @loop=3

while(@loop<=17)
begin
    print concat( @table ,'x',+@loop,'=', +@table*@loop)
    set @loop+=1
end
```

When I see problem I got an mistake on print statement where I was using only variables but I didn't realize they all should have same datatype that what the problem I thought so I researched for `concat` keyword.
it automatically converts all variables and values in between to   datatype that is being  required so I used

```sql
print concat(@table ,'x',+@loop,'=', +@table*@loop)
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a addition to your question?